# extract time from string in r

Tags: regex, r, database, string

I would like to extract some time information (duration) from a string (imported from a database) in R and need some help on how I would approach this task. The problem is there are thousands of durations of time in a database that I would like to process, but they vary in format.
For instance,

String

- 1 day
- 23 hours
- 3-5days
- 7-10 days
- 48 hours

  As you can see, they vary by format, some have a range, some have an exact duration of time, and some have spaces separating the numerals and letters. Ideally, these would process into two columns with a range, then a third column that I could calculate total duration.
  So, the results of the above data points would be:

  Day;Day
- 1;1
- .958;.958
- 3;5
- 7;10
- 2;2

I'm thinking I may need a regexp that extracts the numbers and looks for key words. If the word "hour" is found, do a conversion to days. If a dash is found, find the numbers before and after the dash as well as the keyword "hour/day". This seems like a mess to work through, but wanted to see if anyone had ideas to make my life easier.

Thanks!

Comment: basically, you need to do something like this [https://regex101.com/r/wN1eI9/1](https://regex101.com/r/wN1eI9/1) and then iterater over the list and replace the semicolon at end with `;(same number as preceeding)`

Answer (score 1):

Extract the times, split them by `-`, match them to the hour or day units, convert back to days:

```
# recreate your data:
x <- c("1 day", "23 hours", "3-5days", "7-10 days", "48 hours ")

# identify if hours or days    
per <- c("days","hours")[max.col(sapply(c("day","hour"),grepl,x))]
# get the range of values as numeric data
vals <- lapply(strsplit(regmatches(x, regexpr("(\\d+|\\d+-\\d+)",x)),"-"),as.numeric)
# convert to difftime objects and re-format
lapply(Map(as.difftime, vals, units=per), as.numeric, units="days")

#[[1]]
#[1] 1
# 
#[[2]]
#[1] 0.9583333
# 
#[[3]]
#[1] 3 5
#
#[[4]]
#[1]  7 10
# 
#[[5]]
#[1] 2
```